# ng-model bind to select tag produced empty default value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/z71vqLva/

```
<select ng-model="data.fields.pax">
              <option>pax</option>
              <option value="1">1 pax</option>
              <option value="2">2 pax</option>
            </select>
</div>
```

I put above block into ng-repeat, not sure why the select contain 1 empty value as default value. When u selected something and click the dropdown again, it's gone.

Comment: Try this: `<option value="">pax</option>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an empty value attribute for an empty option tag if you want it to be preselected:

```
<select ng-model="data.fields.pax">
    <option value="">pax</option>
    <option value="1">1 pax</option>
    <option value="2">2 pax</option>
    <option value="3">3 pax</option>
    <option value="4">4 pax</option>
    <option value="5">5 pax</option>
    <option value="6">6 pax</option>
</select>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9pvzf8kd/

Comment: correct answer... since Evandro answered it correctly first... I feel its fair to give him the upvote....in the comment of course :)